# Chaning TextView from a method (Android)

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to use a method to change my TextView, but my code doesnt work.

```
public void change(){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfortune);
    textView.setText("Test");
}
```

But the TextView only disappear.
If I change it directly in a Clicklistner it works fine, but if the Clicklistner starts the method with same code inside it doesnt.
Can anybody explain why? Or how to fix this?

the full code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfortune);

    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (float)0.2*width);

    textView.setText("Fortune");
    textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);






    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
    root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             change();

        }
    });
return true;

}
```

after the click the TextView disappear

Comment: add ur full code! and add more details on what u r trying to do

Comment: This code should work fine... You are missing a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void change(View v){
  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfortune);
  textView.setText("Test");
}
```

In your layout XML set `onClick` attribute for example in your `Button`

```
android:onClick="change"
```

It should work.

Comment: no sorry the text is still disappear , but I dont want to change it with a button click it should change with click on the screen well this works but only if i write the code in the clicklistner. not if I start there an mehtod with same code.

Comment: You can put android:onClick="change" on every element of your UI, Button, TextView, LinearLayout etc.

Comment: I found a way to avoid it but still tank you